# Скрипт не видит $_REQUEST['login'] в Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь реализовать собственную страницу восстановления пароля. Делаю как в этой статье
https://misha.blog/wordpress/stranica-vosstanovleniya-parolya.html
Все работает ровно до того момента когда уже отправляешь форму с новыми паролями, долго ковырялся, наконец то выяснил что переменная с логином по какой то причине в данной функции у меня пустая.

```
    <?php    
add_action( 'login_form_rp', 'to_custom_password_reset' );
add_action( 'login_form_resetpass', 'to_custom_password_reset' );

function to_custom_password_reset(){
            $login = $_REQUEST['login'];
            $key = $_REQUEST['key'];
            $forgot_pass_page_slug = '/password-recovery';
            $login_page_slug = '/login';


                $user = check_password_reset_key( $key, $login );

                if ( ! $user || is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
                    if ( $user && $user->get_error_code() === 'expired_key' ) {
                        wp_redirect( site_url( $login_page_slug . '?errno=expiredkey' ) );
                    } else {
                        wp_redirect( site_url( $login_page_slug . '?errno=invalidkey&'.$key . '&login='.$login ) );
                    }
                    exit;
                }



            if ( 'GET' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {

                $to = site_url( $forgot_pass_page_slug );
                $to = add_query_arg( 'login', esc_attr( $login ), $to );
                $to = add_query_arg( 'key', esc_attr( $key ), $to );

                wp_redirect( $to );
                exit;

            } elseif ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) {

                if ( isset( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {

                    if ( $_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2'] ) {
                        $to = site_url( $forgot_pass_page_slug );

                        $to = add_query_arg( 'key', esc_attr( $key ), $to );
                        $to = add_query_arg( 'login', esc_attr( $login ), $to );
                        $to = add_query_arg( 'errno', 'password_reset_mismatch', $to );

                        wp_redirect( $to );
                        exit;
                    }

                    if ( empty( $_POST['pass1'] ) ) {
                        $to = site_url( $forgot_pass_page_slug );

                        $to = add_query_arg( 'key', esc_attr( $key ), $to );
                        $to = add_query_arg( 'login', esc_attr( $login ), $to );
                        $to = add_query_arg( 'errno', 'password_reset_empty', $to );

                        wp_redirect( $to );
                        exit;
                    }

                    reset_password( $user, $_POST['pass1'] );
                    wp_redirect( site_url( $login_page_slug . '?errno=changed' ) );

                } else {
                    echo "Please try one more time";
                }

                exit;

            }

        } ?>
```

Не понимаю почему так происходит, в POST запросе эта переменная есть, адрес вот такого вида `/password-recovery/?login=yuranthere3&key=5N7qIyxXPCgJ3cH947ur`.
Причем если я на странице формы вывожу `echo $_REQUEST['login'];` , то он без проблем его отображает.Очень нужна помощь, может быть кто то подскажет в чем тут проблема может быть?

Comment: Используйте `$_POST`.

Answer (score 1):

В файле `wp-includes\load.php`, загружаемом на ранней стадии, есть такая строка в функции `wp_magic_quotes()`

```
    // Force REQUEST to be GET + POST.
    $_REQUEST = array_merge( $_GET, $_POST );
```

Если вы попробуете проверить `$_REQUEST` до этого, там будет пусто.

Функция `wp_magic_quotes()` вызывается после загрузки всех плагинов. Я не анализировал, когда срабатывают действия `login_form_rp`, `login_form_resetpass`, но, судя по всему, раньше.

Используйте `$_POST` в ваших функциях.